# Ubuntu 16.04 Ethernet resume after suspend/cold boot

Tags: 16.04, suspend, ethernet, resume

Recently I have had a problem with my Ubuntu MATE desktop not resuming an ethernet connection after suspend, and occasionally after a cold boot.

What usually fixes it is a 'uncheck' Enable Networking via Network Manager GUI - and them re enabling. If not, I reboot which will fix things.

I'm running `lshw -class network`:

```
   *-network
   product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 00
   serial: 60:45:cb:7f:9a:0f
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.8-4 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:122 memory:f7100000-f711ffff
```

My Ethernet connection is static, IPv6 is off on the Wired connection I use on the machine. I have also turned off Power saving via `etc/rc.local` file:

```
!/bin/sh -e
rc.local
```

This script is executed at the end of each multi-user runlevel.
 Make sure that the script will `exit 0` on success or any other
 value on error.

In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
 bits.

By default this script does nothing.

```
sleep 10

ethtool --set-eee enp0s31f6 eee off

ethtool -s enp0s31f6 wol d

exit 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem; it started about a week ago after an update. After restarting the NetworkManager, NM logs `no ifupdown configuration found` and `state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]`. Also, I get `kernel: [21958.684572] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready`.
Status LEDs are on; under Windows 10, there are no problems.
Any ideas?

Comment: Dariok, mine actually resolved itself after an update. Not sure exactly what, but I noticed the issue did not reappear after updates.

Comment: thanks for the update. I hope, mine will resolve itself, too.

Comment: I've just been going through `powertop` and noticed that „Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM“ was set to on (which is reported as „Good“ under „Tunables“) – switching this off immediately brought the ethernet back. I don't remember setting this option, so it is possible that this gets automatically set by some mechanism. I'll keep an eye on it and report back.

Answer (score 0):

In `powertop`, under *Tunables*, look for "Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM"; if it is enabled (*Good*), toggle it to switch the feature off (reported as *Bad*).
In my case, it immediately brought the ethernet back online.